# Showing a power series converges...

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'd like to show that $$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{{x^{n + 1}}} \over {n(n + 1)}}} $$ absolutely converges for $|x| < 1$

Comment: What about applying the ratio test?

Comment: I will try that, thank you.

Comment: The terms are bounded by $x^{n+1}$, which are known to form a convergent geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), we can write for the given series,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{x^{n + 2}} {(n+1)(n+2)}}{\frac{x^{n + 1}}{n(n + 1)}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x}{1+\frac{2}{n}} = x$$

So this is a geometric series with common ratio $x$ which converges iff $|x|<1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \left|{{{{x^{n + 1}}} \over {n(n + 1)}}}\right|<\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{{|x|^{n + 1}}}} }=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^2\frac{1-|x|^n}{1-|x|}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}<1$ then the series (with no zero terms) $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge0}a_n$ absolutely converges.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this directly:

If $|x|<1$, then $|x^{n+1}|<1$, so for any $N>n$, we have

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}\right| \le \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{|x^{n+1}|}{n(n+1)}\le\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n(n+1)} =\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right) = 1-\frac1{N+1}\,.$$